# why this statement is not working? if (Status = 'T') then (cast(date] as varchar) else (' ')

Tags: postgresql-9.1

why this statement is not working?

```
if (Status = 'T') then (cast(date] as varchar)   else (' ')
```

Thanks
Aj

Comment: What is not working? What do the relevant table and data look like? What other variants have you tried?

Comment: When status = 'T' the data in date column is not showing

Comment: Please create a [MCVE].

Comment: There is no `IF` statement in SQL. Also `]` has to be `)`

Answer (score 0):

[IF is plpgsql, not SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS).

I assume you try this:

```
case when Status = 'T' then cast(date as varchar) else '' end as aliasname
```